# How to create a dictionary that shows which values of another dictionary belong to which keys

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary: `{26:['hello', 'test'], 27:['hello', 'good', 'morning', 'test']}`
I need to create a new dictionary with as key the word and as value a list whith the keys in which it exists as a value, it should look like this: `dict1 = {'hello':[26,27], 'test':[26,27], 'good':[27], 'morning':[27]}`
To try to solve my problem, I already created a list with all the words without duplicates, so `words = ['hello', 'test', 'good', 'morning']`. Then I tried this:

```
newdict = {} 

for i in words:
            l = []
            for k in dict1:
                if i in dict1[k]:
                    l.append(k)
                newdict[i] = l
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I created a list with all the words without duplicates, so ````words = ['hello', 'test', 'good', 'morning']````. Then I tried this: ```newdict = {} for i in words:
            l = []
            for k in original_dict:
                if i in original_dict[k]:
                    l.append(k)
                newdict[i] = l ```

Comment: Please add that to the question instead

Comment: Well that works. So what is the issue you faced? Also fix up your indentation

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it didn't work. But the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without imports you can do it like this:

```
a = {26:['hello', 'test'], 27:['hello', 'good', 'morning', 'test']}
result = {}

for k, v in a.items():
    for item in v:
        result[item] = result.get(item, []) + [k]
```

The `dict. get(key[, default])` is explained [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html).
So, your result dict will either return it's value or empty list.

After that you can simply use `+` operator which is concatenation operator in case of lists.

Take note that list concatenation works only between lists, so we are wrapping the value in `[]` making it a list containing the key.

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe explain how the final line works?

Comment: This solution works in O(n**2) pessimistic time (where n is the number of strings in the original dictionary)

Comment: @zipa Think what happen's when the original dictionary is `{1: ['a'], 2: ['a'], 3: ['a'], 4: ['a'], 5: ['a'], ..., n: ['a']}`
You will execute `result[item] = result.get(item, []) + [k]` n times, each time creating a copy of the previous state of `result['a']` extended by one element.

Comment: @grześ which makes it `O(n)`. If you are considering the scaling factor `collections.defaultdict` is a go to for you.

Comment: First you copy 1-el list, then 2-el list, then 3-el, finally you copy (n-1)-el list. It takes O(n**2) time.
The point is: don't use concatenation, unless you really need a copy. Use append/extend methods.

Comment: @grześ That results in `O(2n)` and scalar (2) isn't used when defining complexity so the notation is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the inversion operation that turns `{k:[v]}` into `{v:[k]}`:

```
output = {}
for k,v in input.items():
   for e in v:
     output.setdefault(e, []).append(k)
```

Comment: I always forget about `setdefault` :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {26:['hello', 'test'], 27:['hello', 'good', 'morning', 'test']} 
result = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in data.items():
    for item in v:
        result[item].append(k)
print(result)
```

---

Using `setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    for item in v:
        result.setdefault(item, []).append(k)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'test': [26, 27], 'good': [27], 'hello': [26, 27], 'morning': [27]})
{'test': [26, 27], 'good': [27], 'hello': [26, 27], 'morning': [27]}
```